# Stacked multi dimensional bar chart Apache superset

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

In Apache superset i have a dataset, columns are Q9_1 to Q9_7, each representing a question.
Each row has value 1 or 2 depending on if the answer is Yes or No. Like this example data;

```
q9_1;q9_2;q9_3;q9_4;q9_5;q9_6;q9_7
2;2;2;1;2;2;2
1;2;1;1;2;1;2
1;1;1;2;2;2;1
1;1;2;1;2;2;2
2;2;2;1;2;1;2
1;1;1;2;2;1;2
1;1;2;1;1;1;2
1;2;2;2;1;1;1
1;2;2;2;1;2;1
1;1;1;2;2;2;2
2;2;2;2;1;1;2
1;2;1;1;2;1;1
1;2;2;2;2;2;2
```

Now, I would like to display this all in one bar chart. Each bar representing Q9_1 to Q9_7, with the percentage of Yes stacked on top of percentage of No.

I was able to do this by creating a custom dataset from a SQL-query, however, I would like to able to filter the data if i were to add more information to each row, like sex or residential area, so then the custom dataset doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pivot Table function to compute ratios, and then create a Stacked Bar Chart in Apache Superset to display percentages of "Yes" and "No" for questions Q9_1 through Q9_7. For dynamic analysis, you can set filters for extra data like sex or residential area. The chart can be shared and saved for quick access.

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Well, this is what i have already tried.
When I add all the columns Q9_1 through Q9_7 to Dimensions and put Count(*) as metrics it displays a chart for each possible combination like;
"1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0" and "2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0" and so forth.

Feels like the Dimensions or Metrics should be some sort of aggregate or CASE.